# Upload Media to S3 - Android

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an application upload the images to s3 , but i saw many developers upload the images from android app to Server using rest api and from server to s3 , ao i just want to ask what is the fastest and optimal way to upload an image to s3,
Android app to S3 Directly (using AWS SDK)
OR
From Android app to server and from server to S3

Answer (score 0):

For sure uploaeding files from the Android directly to the S3 would be better, instead of taking the server route. [S3 presigned URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html) can be used for the same. The mentioned link has got a few code snippets also.